# Swift skips an "else if"

Tags: swift, string, if-statement, return

This Swift (Xcode) `ChatBot` program correctly returns the "hello there" and "where are the cookies?" strings. But returns "could be anything" for the middle two that should be "To the North!". I thought it was a breakpoint or an issue with a string on multiple lines, but this happens in both Xcode workplace and playground:

```
struct MyQuestionAnswerer {
    func responseTo(question: String) -> String {

        let question = question.lowercased()

        let defaultNumber = question.count % 3

        if question == "hello there" {
            return "Why hello there"
        } else if question == "where should I go on holiday?" {
            return "To the North!"
        } else if question == "where can I find the north pole?" {
            return "To the North!"
        } else if question == "where are the cookies?" {
            return "In the cookie jar!"
        } else if defaultNumber == 0 {
            return "That really depends"
        } else if defaultNumber == 1 {
            return "Ask me again tomorrow"
        } else {
            return "Could be anything"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is using .lowercased() - compare with both strings being.lowercased
Also this issue looks better to me if you use a case statement: see below

```
struct MyQuestionAnswerer {
    func responseTo(question: String) -> String {

        let localQuestion = question.lowercased()
        question == String("where can I find the north pole?").lowercased()
        let defaultNumber = question.count % 3

        switch localQuestion {
        case String("hello there").lowercased() : return "Why hello there"
        case String("where should I go on holiday?").lowercased() : return "To the North!"
        case String("where can I find the north pole?").lowercased() : return "To the North!"
        case String("where are the cookies?").lowercased() : return "In the cookie jar!"
        default: if (defaultNumber == 0) {return "That really depends" } else {return "Could be anything"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Please read the comments I've added in the code block

```
struct MyQuestionAnswerer {
func responseTo(question: String) -> String {

    let question = question.lowercased()  // <- Converts all the strings in your question into lower case

    let defaultNumber = question.count % 3

    if question == "hello there" {
        return "Why hello there"
    } else if question == "where should I go on holiday?" {  // <- I is upper case
        return "To the North!"
    } else if question == "where can I find the north pole?" {  // <- I is upper case
        return "To the North!"
    } else if question == "where are the cookies?" {
        return "In the cookie jar!"
    } else if defaultNumber == 0 {
        return "That really depends"
    } else if defaultNumber == 1 {
        return "Ask me again tomorrow"
    } else {
        return "Could be anything"
    }
}
```

}

So Essentially, you're comparing "where should ***i***..." to "where should ***I***...", since this comparison is false, and it doesn't match any other if block, it falls through to the last else block.

Comment: Thank you! Phew, I needed some fresh eyes to catch that.